# Close YesNo MessageBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

It (MessageBox) checks if a file is saved or not

I want to close the Form when clicking Yes

and to return to the app when clicking No

I searched a lot in the documents and questions but didn't find an answer

I mean, there is "MessageBox.Show()",
Isn't there "MessageBox.Close()" ??

That's what I have:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = "The File Is Not Saved\nDo You Want To Close?";
            var title = "File Not Saved";
            var buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;

            if (FSaved == false)
            {
                var res = MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons);
                if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (res == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have you cancel the close with the event args - `e`.

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

You also shouldn't call `Close()` from `FormClosing` as it is already on the way out.

Comment: @BasemSleem: It may help you to know there are several layers involved.  The underlying `event` feature of .NET is a *very* flexible callback system -- the callback can take any number of parameters, with any types, and even return values.  Then WinForms applies a design pattern to its own events, where every event handler takes two arguments, the first is always `sender`, the second is always derived from `EventArgs`.  And then each individual WinForms event has its own rules for what data appears inside its EventArgs parameter.